# Why do database schemas often contain 32, 64, 128, etc

Tags: sql, database, binary, byte

I understand that 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256... are the decimal equivalents of binary digits.

Is there a reason why these are used in databases? For example, VARCHAR fields are often 255 characters long. Since (I'm assuming) each character is one byte, why is there a difference between using 255 characters and using 257 characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `varchar` columns, the *length* is stored *with* the data using unsigned integers in the leading bytes of the data. The fewest number of bytes is used; one byte can store lengths from 0 to 255, two bytes from 0 to 65535, etc. By making the length 255, you get the "most value" out of the minimum one length byte.

In days gone by, single bytes of disk saved per row were worth saving. Although now disk is cheap, the thinking has remained, especially by grey-haired DBAs.

There is no advantage in choosing a length that is a power of 2, for example `varchar(64)` - it is merely a habit/convention (I even follow it - and I don't know why!).

Comment: Ouch. I have grey hair but I'm not that old (38). :-)

Comment: Hmm, though in large tables where you need to make SELECT calls requiring lots of I/Os, saving a few bytes of row size *can* make a difference.  (But you're absolutely right about VARCHAR length though :)

Comment: @osman yes - the more rows and/or index entries you can fit in 1 page of disk the better the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not merely database schemas but pretty much any programming artifact will by found to contain many numbers of the form 2^N or 2^N-1.  While some of these uses make sense (e.g. 2^32-1 being the largest number representable as a standard unsigned integer in many machine architectures), most uses of powers of 2 are less necessary.   In practice, old hackers view powers of 2 as holy, and venerate them such.

Comment: How else are things going to line up nicely when you view a hex dump of your data? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The data in databases is often organized in [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401910/mysql-what-is-a-page). These pages are almost universally aligned with memory boundaries for memory and cache management. Choosing 2^n sizes for your data is good to optimize the use of space in your database.

Note: Depending on the RDBMS engine, 256 may not be the best choice for variable-length strings from the memory alignment perspective, because the length of the string takes space as well, i.e. a `varchar(256)` takes up 258 bytes.

Comment: Unless the data sizes are fixed (char/nchar), this doesn't hold true for varying length columns, which are far more likely to be defined using these magic numbers, and which are rarely populated completely and therefore do not evenly fill a page in nice little blocks.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's the point I tried to make in the note at the end of the answer: 2^n numbers for `varchar` columns is unlikely to help with page alignment.

Comment: Sorry, I started my comment after finishing the first paragraph. Suggest saying something about "fixed data" instead of just "data" in case other people also don't read your note. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is more habit than anything. There is nothing magic about varchar(32) or varchar(64), similarly there is nothing magic about the defaults the visual tools try to make you use instead (e.g. varchar(50)). A lot of these upper bounds have been ingrained into people's heads since 640k would be enough memory for anyone and we really needed to worry about every single byte.

In a lot of cases it comes down to a common ground. In a previous system I worked in the product managers had no idea what their requirements were. They wanted to store a name, but they didn't know what the domain of names really consisted of - but one of them stated that they had heard of a last name > 50 characters, so he knew it had to be more than 32 and more than 50. We came back with 64, he agreed that was enough, and that is what is still there today AFAIK.

Though we did have a technical reason for e-mail (varchar(320)), which at the time the standard dictated as 320 characters because 64 characters for username/localpart, 255 characters for domain name, and 1 character for @. Most other decisions were based on precedence (e.g. all subsequent names followed the nvarchar(64) model as decided above), or logic (e.g. URLs don't need to be nvarchar(max), but depending on the standard and browser capabilities at the time, they were I believe either varchar(2048) or varchar(4096). In that case not because it was a power of 2, but because someone else's software or standards built their stuff to use a power of 2.

Comment: +1 because you (I think) recommend consulting standards e.g. for person family name I'd use `VARCHAR(35)` to match [my country's government data standards](http://interim.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/govtalk/schemasstandards/e-gif/datastandards/person_information/person_name/person_full_name.aspx), partly because my software is likely to interact with government databases but also because someone has done the analysis to determine that 35 non-Unicode characters is a reasonable constraint so that I don't have to!

Comment: Yes, absolutely, if there are data standards for your industry, you should use them. But your customers and product managers - who are also your customers - may often dictate otherwise, and their trump usually beats a standard's trump (unless they're being stupid or ridiculous). And they will test out whether you really do allow a 64-character last name, trust me. :-)

Comment: I wonder whether, if someone suggests using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`,  I would be justified in taking [a leaf out of Joe Celko's book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a9jtyioHfp8C&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=celko+buddhist&source=bl&ots=Py_oNKC6_h&sig=d9MRYEcVlI-Noi03XWLaDhAv6WM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D0VGT6SzAYbN0QXa7KmmDg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) and putting Chinese Unicode in there? ;)

Comment: I think `NVARCHAR` is becoming the reality here. People can get pretty offended when you drop these things from their name inadvertently. Try `DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'Ȃaron';
SELECT @x;`... I wouldn't brush `NVARCHAR` off so easily for things where you might only see `VARCHAR` now - your requirements may change in the future and that change is going to hurt more.

Comment: The biggest objection to `NVARCHAR` is the wasted space for all the non-Unicode characters, but you should read about Unicode compression in 2008 R2 - it actually negates this argument quite well. I wrote three blog posts about this: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/tags/Unicode+compression/default.aspx